# CSS select element with particular child element attribute

Tags: html, css

I have a lot of right-aligned images. Simplified Wordpress html looks like this:

```
<div class="wp-block-image">
  <figure class="alignright">
    <img width="387" height="500" src='****some-pic-387x500.jpg">
  </figure>
</div>
```

I need `CSS` selectors to select both certain figure elements and the corresponding img elements. Ideally I would like to select for img elements above a certain width, but all my reading tells me that is impossible.

Alternatively, I can select for img elements whose src attribute does not contain "triangle". This successfully selects such `img` elements:

```
.wp-block-image figure.alignright img:not([src*="triangle"]) {
    max-width: 99%;
}
```

The problem is, I can't figure out how to select the corresponding (parent) figure element.  I've tried this but it fails:

```
.wp-block-image figure.alignright:has(img:not([src*="triangle"])) {
    margin: 0.5em;
}
```

It seems `has()` is [not supported](https://caniuse.com/css-has) by any browser. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: As a reminder, the Wordpress tag is for programming-specific questions about the WordPress content management system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your complex selector in CSS, plain JS and using the jQuery lib... Guess who wins!

```js
// Checking if JS handles that selector....

// Let's have the selector in a variable, just to make sure the same is tried in both cases...
let ourSelector = ".wp-block-image figure.alignright:has(img:not([src*='triangle']))"

// JS querySelector
try{
  document.querySelector(ourSelector).style.border = "3px solid blue";
}
catch(error){
  console.log(error.message);
}

// jQuery! (--WORKS--)
$(ourSelector).css("border", "3px solid blue");
```

```css
/* This rule applies */
.wp-block-image figure.alignright img:not([src*="triangle"]) {
  border: 3px solid red;
}


/* This one not */
.wp-block-image figure.alignright:has(img:not([src*="triangle"])) {
    opacity: 0.2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wp-block-image">
  <figure class="alignright">
    <img width="387" height="500" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300.jpg?text=triangle" />
  </figure>
  <figure class="alignright">
    <img width="387" height="500" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300?text=square" />
  </figure>
</div>
```

So until the browser implementations evolve... I think your solution is jQuery.

Comment: Both answers seem to work, but this one may be a bit simpler and is amazingly well demonstrated.  I'm going to have to figure out how to add javascript or jQuery.

Comment: Thank for the *amazingly well demonstrated* comment! ;) Now I have to underline the fact that, if you do not already use jQuery, the other answer is better. If you already have jQuery loaded, mine is simpler. ;)

Answer (score 3):

You already have the selector for any `figure.alignright img` where the `src` attribute does not contain "triangle":

```
.wp-block-image figure.alignright img:not([src*="triangle"])
```

So, you can use **that selector** in a dash of javascript, like this:

```
// GET ALL QUALIFIED ELEMENTS
const qualifiedElements = [...document.querySelectorAll('.wp-block-image figure.alignright img:not([src*="triangle"])')];

// ADD CLASSES TO EACH QUALIFIED ELEMENT AND ITS PARENT NODE 
for (qualifiedElement of qualifiedElements) {

  qualifiedElement.classList.add('qualified-element');
  qualifiedElement.parentNode.classList.add('qualified-element-parent');
}
```

And then you can include the following CSS in your stylesheet:

```
.qualified-element {
    max-width: 99%;
}

.qualified-element-parent {
    margin: 0.5em;
}
```